# ERROR 1064 (42000) database error in syntax of over partition by

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, mysql-5.7

```
mysql> select * from FinalTable;
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | name  | state | timestamp           |
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   12 | name1 | TX    | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
|   14 | name3 | CA    | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
|   14 | name3 | TX    | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
|   12 | name1 | CA   | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
|   13 | name2 | TA   | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
|   14 | name3 |  CA   | 2020-01-25 11:29:36 |
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

I am looking at output query which gives response as:

```
I2 name1 TX 2020-01-25 11:29:36  CA 2020-01-25 11:29:36
```

when I run the query,

```
select id,name,state,timestamp,
lead(state,1) over (partition by id order by timestamp asc) out_state,
lead(timestamp,1) over (partition by id order by timestamp asc) out_timestamp
from FinalTable

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by id order by timestamp asc) out_state,
lead(timestamp,1) over (part' at line 2
```

also is it possible to create timetamp upto milliseconds instead of seconds in DB?
I am using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: Ver 14.14 distrib 5.7.28 Ubantu

Answer (score 1):

Window functions (such as `lead()`) were added in MySQL 8.0 only, so they are not available in version 5.7. You can emulate `lead()` with a self-join like so:

```
select t.*, tlead.state, tlead.timestamp
from FinalTable t
left join FinalTable tlead 
    on tlead .id = t.id
    and tlead.timestamp = (
        select min(t1.timestamp) 
        from FinalTable t1 
        where t1.id = t.id and t1.timestamp > t.timestamp
    )
```

Side note: for this method to work properly, you need subsequent records of the same `id` to have different `timestamp`s - which is not the case in the sample data that you showed, where all timestamps are the same (I assume this is a typo in your sample data).

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to upgrade to mysql8 based on ur comment thankq. also how can I set time in milliseconds