# Sql calculating derived data based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table in mysql database which has time series data

```
**Table Sensor Data**  
ID    uuid  server_time
1      a    2021-07-29 11:36:15
2      b    2021-07-29 11:36:15
3      a    2021-07-29 12:36:15
4      b    2021-07-29 11:39:15
```

Now for every sensor with a given uuid if the next data entry according to server_time has a gap of more than 30 minutes, its considered to be an offline entry and if its less than 30 minutes its considered an online entry. I need to find total counts of online entries and offline entries in  a month. Since this data is very big, I don't want to do it in application. How can I do it in the db itself using query or some function/script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select year(server_time), month(server_time),
       sum( next_server_time < server_time + interval 30 minute ) as cnt_online,
       sum( next_server_time >= server_time + interval 30 minute ) as cnt_offline
from (select sd.*,
             lead(server_time) over (partition by uuid) as next_server_time
      from sensordata sd
     ) sd
group by year(server_time), month(server_time)
```

Comment: Is there any performance benefit of using partition over a normal join query like mentioned in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59912475/2462868

Comment: @devJoshi . . . Window functions are more concise, less error-prone, and usually have better performance.